# Issue with copying processed data back to Java from Renderscript

Tags: android, image-processing, renderscript

**Summary**

I am passing a struct containing constant size float array to the renderscript forEach function. My issue has been getting the data back to Java.

**Background**

I'm working on optimizing an image processing algorithm using RenderScript.  The FAE for the board manufacturer claims that OpenCL isn't supported on our hardware and that Google "doesn't particularly care" for OpenCL.  The SOM we're using has a Vivante GC2000 GPGPU and there is support for OpenCL according to the hardware documentation.  All that not withstanding, RenderScript became the technology we decided on.

**Problem Description**

To test the Renderscript setup for the application, I created a 100x100 array of float with constant test data.  The data seems to be making it to the Renderscript layer because I can print the results using rsDebug and they match the expected values.  After doing some filtering on the array, I can see that the array has been modified. However, when I pass the array back to Java (see source below), I do not see the modifications.

**What I've Tried**

Since the beginning of this project, I've tried a myriad of approaches that didn't seem to gain traction.

At first, I implemented the renderscript portion in c++.  I switched to Java because I couldn't get the c++ class to reflect properly and the documentation for using NDK and renderscript together is even more sparse than the Java APIs.  I assumed it's a bug in the llvm rs compiler because it fails when it tries to generates the class header.  It generates a file with a single '/' and it appears to be failing when it attempts to insert the attribution stuff at the top.

I've also tried the support library with the same results; the output data isn't populated.

I've tried copying the data from a bound pointer to primitives and the row/column struct.  I also tried using rsElementSetAt/rsElementGetAt and still nothing.

I've tried to use the older forEach signatue: void root(...) instead of the attribute version.  I was still unable to get the processed data out.  I also tried various ways of actually invoking the forEach function by setting a global script and global allocations for in/out and invoking a function that calls rsForEach.

I tried to copy the data as various primitives, but an exception is thrown due to inconsistent 'type' values (for the allocation holding the DataUnit structs, the type is NONE).

**Actual Question**

Based on this information, can anyone tell if I'm doing something/not doing something right?  It seems like it should work, but I've had no luck with this.  If someone has any insight about this, I would greatly appreciate hearing it.  Thanks!

**testscript.rs**

```
typedef struct DataUnit {
float rows[100];
float cols[100];
} DataUnit_t;

DataUnit_t __attribute__((kernel)) oldtest(DataUnit_t v_in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    DataUnit_t tmpd;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        float a = -1, b = -1, c = -1;
        switch(i) {
            case 0:
                a = 0;
                b = v_in.cols[i];
                c = v_in.cols[i+1];
                break;
            case 99:
                a = v_in.cols[i-1];
                b = v_in.cols[i];
                c = 0;
                break;
            default:
                a = v_in.cols[i-1];
                b = v_in.cols[i];
                c = v_in.cols[i+1];
                break;
        }

        tmpd.cols[i] = 11.3f;
        //v_out.cols[i] = (float)(((a/4.0f)+(b/2.0f)+(c/4.0f))/3);
    }
// From using the old kernel signature (root)
    //*v_out = tmpd;

    return tmpd;
 }
```

**Initialization in Java**

```
ScriptField_DataUnit dataOut = new ScriptField_DataUnit(mRS, 100);
ScriptField_DataUnit dataIn = new ScriptField_DataUnit(mRS, 100);
for(int i = 0; i < mWidth; i++) {
    ScriptField_DataUnit.Item item = new ScriptField_DataUnit.Item();
    for(int j = 0; j < item.rows.length; j++) {
        // Set the positions of the columns and rows
        item.rows[j] = (float)mBufIn[(i*mWidth)+j];
        item.cols[j] = (float)mBufIn[(j*mHeight)+i];
    }
    dataIn.set(item, i, false);
    // Not sure about setting dataOut items. If this isn't done, 
// the members holding the actual data are null but it's unclear if this is the way to do it
    dataOut.set(new ScriptField_DataUnit.Item(), i, false);
}
dataIn.copyAll();
dataOut.copyAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to bind memory allocated by Java to the RenderScript runtime before calling forEach_oldtest(): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/advanced.html#allocating-mem